# Sort strings by index number of word (the number is given as an argument) in java

Tags: java

For example if I know for certain that I need sort by second word. I can create Comparator like this.

```
class SecondWordComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        String[] a1 = s1.split(" ");
        String[] a2 = s2.split(" ");

        return a1[1].compareTo(a2[1]);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to give another index number of word to Comparator through an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not through an *argument (parameter)* to `Comparator`, no, but you can either:

1. Make it a field of your `Comparator` concrete class, or
2. If you implement `Comparator` as an anonymous class it can be a `final` variable or parameter the implementation closes over

#1 is fairly trivial. Here's an example of #2 ([live copy](http://ideone.com/AWya4V)):

```
import java.util.*;

class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String[] strings = new String[] {
            "one two three",
            "uno due tre",
            "uno dos tres",
            "un deux trois"
        };
        sort(strings, 2); // 2 = third word
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static void sort(String[] strings, final int index) {
        Arrays.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2)
            {
                String[] a1 = s1.split(" ");
                String[] a2 = s2.split(" ");
                String word1 = a1.length > index ? a1[index] : "";
                String word2 = a2.length > index ? a2[index] : "";

                return word1.compareTo(word2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding a method from an interface

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2)
```

then adding a parameter in the method signature violates the declarede method in the interface....

so is not possible...

java is very flexible language so you can always implement anonymous instances of the **comparator**...